# OpenLayers 2 - Set fill and opacity to Polygon Style

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

My goal is to use for different shapes (*Triangle, Circle, Square, Hexagon etc.*) different fill colors and opacity values for each shape.

With the below code I can draw the shapes, set different titles and stroke colors. But I'm not able to set the fill color and the opacity values.

I checked the documentation and its looks like I could achieve this with "fillColor" and "fillOpacity" but it doesn't works.

```js
  function GetLonLatObj(lat, lon){
 
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( lon ,lat )
        .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // Transformation aus dem Koordinatensystem WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // in das Koordinatensystem 'Spherical Mercator Projection'
        );
        
         return lonLat
    }
  
    var points = []
    var fontColor = "blue";
    var title = "Test";
    
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");

    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var zoom=16;

    latLonPoint = GetLonLatObj("46.76", "7.606944444444444");
    latLonPoint2 = GetLonLatObj("46.735", "7.543055555555555");
    latLonPoint3 = GetLonLatObj("46.7169444", "7.569166666666667");
    latLonPoint4 = GetLonLatObj("46.76", "7.606944444444444");
        
    latPoint = latLonPoint.lat
    lonPoint = latLonPoint.lon
        
    latPoint2 = latLonPoint2.lat
    lonPoint2 = latLonPoint2.lon
        
    latPoint3 = latLonPoint3.lat
    lonPoint3 = latLonPoint3.lon
        
    latPoint4 = latLonPoint4.lat
    lonPoint4 = latLonPoint4.lon

    //var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(828260.4259880, 5933577.75538379);
    point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonPoint, latPoint);
    point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonPoint2, latPoint2);
    point3 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonPoint3, latPoint3);
    point4 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonPoint4, latPoint4);

    points.push(point);
    points.push(point2);
    points.push(point3);
    points.push(point4);
                    
    var selected_polygon_style = {
        
        strokeWidth: "3",
        strokeColor: fontColor,
        fontColor: "red",
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontColor: "black",
        label: title
    };
    
    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
    
    vectorLayer.style = selected_polygon_style;
    //map.addLayers([vector]);
 
    vectorLayer.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points))]);
 
    map.addLayers([vectorLayer]);
    
    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);
    
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(latLonPoint));
    
    map.setCenter (latLonPoint, zoom);
```

```html
<script src="https://buhli.dyndns.org:444/openlayers.js"></script>

<html>
<body>

  <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me here?

Thank you very much and best regards

Comment: Can you put more code, for example `item.Points`

Comment: I've adjusted it, hope it's okay

Comment: It's better to make a snippet.

Comment: What exactly do you need? The whole script I can't give you. There are lot of functions which has nothing to do with my question. I tried to put here the relevant snippets and explain a bit. If it's not clear, I can try it to rewrite again.

Comment: You've got a "snippet" option when you write a question. You can make a reproductible example, it's easier to answer.

Comment: That means you need a snippet and than you can give me the answer how I can set the fill and opacity?

Comment: Yes, you'll get faster answers on StackOverflow if you give users snippets.

Comment: I added a snippet. The snippet worked on my computer, but unfortunately nothing happens here. Did I do something wrong? Or is this code snippet already enough that sombody can tell me the anser of my question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the LineString in the follow command.

```
vectorLayer.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points))]);
```

I could fix it with it as I replaced with LinearRing.

A LinearRing is a special LineString which is closed. A LineString can but must not be closed.